# Failover with sticky MAC address on network switch

Tags: mac-address, failover, switchport

***Introduction:***

I am configuring a server to have two ethernet ports (one as primary, the other is redundant) connected to two different switches. In the switches, I enabled the sticky MAC address and configured the two ports on the server as Net Switch Team and fixed a MAC address for the team.

***the issue:***

when doing the failover test, I unplugged the primary and the redundant link was up (as expected) but when I unplug the redundant before restoring the primary then restoring both links the server will not be able to ping the switch unless I turn off the Sticky MAC address off in the switches.

***Note:***

I am thinking maybe because the Ethernet Adapter Card has both ports in it and if I applied the same thing on two different ports in two different Ethernet adapter cards it will work fine. Is that true? and if yes why?

Thanks in advanced,
Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sticky MAC doesn't work because you're programming the network to have that MAC in a specific place (port). A MAC can only be in *one* place in the network. If that port is physically up, that's always where the traffic will go. When a MAC is pinned to two places -- on different switches, traffic on each of those switches will *always* flow to the local port, because that's how you've programmed it: Sticky MAC permanently populates the CAM table. A third switch will see that MAC bouncing from switch to switch depending on where it sees traffic. [In Cisco terms a "MAC FLAP"] With a MAC pinned to more than one place, you're relying on the redundant port(s) to be physically down, so the MAC is removed from the CAM table; when they aren't traffic doesn't go where it must.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't entirely clear how the host fails over but the basic approach for active/passive is *don't configure anything on the switch*.

Instead, the host just needs to transmit a single frame with the redundant MAC address as source (physical or virtual), so the switch moves that MAC to the currently active port on failover or recovery. Making a MAC sticky on a certain port may prevent that mechanism from working, depending on the overall configuration.

Comment: Could you please explain why making a MAC sticky on a certain port will prevent this mechanism?

Comment: also, I have enabled port teaming and fixed a MAC address for both ports so they have the same MAC address.

Comment: Please add the full, sanitized switch config to your question using the `{}` preformat option. What is it that you are trying to achieve with stickiness?

Comment: In fact I don't need to have the sticky feature on, but I want to understand why when I enable the port teaming in (SEL-3390E4 network adapter -both ports in the same network adapter-) and I start testing the failover I am unable to ping the switch even if I restored both links

Comment: I'm afraid, host configurations and issues are explicitly off topic here, see the [help/on-topic] - especially when we have no details on how the 'port teaming' really works (there are several ways to do it).

Comment: this issue only appears if enabled the Sticky feature, otherwise the failover works well.

Comment: Then you seem to have your solution.

Comment: My question is why it happens when the sticky is on? I want to know the reason

Comment: The exact behavior depends on the config - *please add the full, sanitized switch config to your question using the {} preformat option.*

Comment: I only enabled the sticky and used the default configuration